# How long does it take to reach deimos?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a planet is 93,341,952 km away and you use a space shuttle, which travels at a speed of 28,000 km/hr to get there, how many days would it take to reach your destination?

Comment: Divide distance by speed. That will give you the time in hours. Then divide by $24$ to get days. Unrealistic problem, no real spacecraft would go in a straight line. Nor at constant speed.

Comment: Title/body disconnect --- Deimos isn't a planet.

Answer (score 4):

Good hint 1: Travelling at a constant speed, time is distance divided by speed.

Good hint 2: You may need to adjust between hours and days.

Bad hint 3: Planets move relative to each other.

Bad hint 4: Martian days are slightly longer than Earth days.

Bad hint 5: You may need to accelerate and decelerate.

Comment: Maybe one more? Really Bad Hint : Interplanetary travel usually requires you to "slingshot" yourself using gravitational fields of larger planets (Called [gravity assist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist)). Also, why the mathematica tag?

Comment: What makes you think you can get there w/ a space shuttle?

Comment: Actually you can't go anywhere with a space shuttle any more: they've all been retired.  But they could never go higher than 1000 km or so above the earth's surface.